# I do not understand how to use @MapKey

Tags: java, hibernate

I use the annotation hibernate i have thise source

```
     @Table(name = "stats")
        public class Stat {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
            @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
            private long id;

            @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
            @JoinColumn(name = "player_id")
            private PPlayer player;

            @Column(name = "stat_type")
            private int type;

            @Column(name = "stat_value")
            private int value;

        }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Users")
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
        public class PPlayer {

            @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
        @Column(name = "user_id")
        private long id;

        private String username;
        private String email;
        private Date joiningDate;
        private String key;
        private String password;

        private int rank;
        private int score;

            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "player", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
                @MapKey(name = "type")
                private Map<Integer, Stat> stats;
        }
```

I watched a lot of documentation but I can not make out @MapKey

What means the `name = "type"?` why `"type"`? the class in which I can view it?
and where i can found `mappedBy = "player"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mappedBy='player'` refers to the `player` attribute fo the `Stat` class - it is the owning side of the relation.

The `name = "type"` refers to the `type` attribute of the same `Stat` class - it says that the values in the `Map` are mapped to different types of `Stat`.

**EDIT**: It may be confusing that the values in the annotation do not correspond to table column names. Column names default to field names, but in your entities the column names are overridden, using the `@Column` annotation

Hibernate and JPA use field names for relation annotations, not column names, except when specified otherwise (like `JoinColumn` etc).

A good heuristic to remember is - when there is no 'column' in the annotation, you can assume that the field name is concerned. I am not sure if it applies 100%, but in most cases it does.

Comment: I showed the class Stat, because in annotation - "type" and "player" missing in class Stat.. class Stat have "stat_type" (type int) and "player_id" (type PPlayer) or I do not understand?

Comment: @MaxUsanin - it seems to be a misunderstanding - I have added some more info to clarify, please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following hibernate manual: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html

Although the above manual deals with XML ORM mapping using Map collections, the underlying principles are pretty much the same with the annotated `@MapKey` usage in Hibernate.

Answer (score -4):

You can look for the JavaDoc of [MapKey](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/MapKey.html).

Comment: Sorry but this link does not tell me anything

Comment: -1 come on, why not suggest using google as well? this is not really helpful